# Thread 1: "-[Xylophone.ViewController buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff83a6074e0"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsexception

> Exception NSException *   "-[Xylophone.ViewController buttonClicked:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x7faa47409400"   0x0000600002148690

I'm trying to make a xylophone app in which the buttons would play different sounds, there are 7 buttons however only the first button doesn't work, all other buttons work. on pressing the first button the app crashes.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
    }
    
    func playSound(soundName:String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
        
        
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
                
    }
}
```

what is the issue here?

Comment: You defined previously a method named `buttonClicked` and now it's been renamed `keyPressed:`, no? But you did the link in the Storyboard with the previous name. So undo the link, and redo it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and here's how I solved it:
right-click every button you have in `Main.storyboard`, and check the connection it has in the small menu like this:
[image]

When I had more than one connection it gave me this error.